# Retrofit,onResponse method doesnt work

Tags: android, retrofit, android-recyclerview, retrofit2

Im new in Retrofit,try to get data from one web server,create Model,Interface but this still not working.Problem(maybe) in method onResponse() I add to that method Log.d and Toast but I dont see Log and Toast when launch my app.Why that dont work? I can understand when I get wrong response or something else,but onResponse() dont work in general,how I think.Maybe Toast cant work withoud data,but Log.d must work without it,and Log.d havent data,just code of response. I added all depencies and tryind do this like in all tutorial,what wrong I did and what I can do to fix that? And also I try tu put this data to adapter,but when launch app,I have error in Log "RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout" maybe it's the same problem.onResponse dont work and adapter doesn't create,because adapter inilialze in onResponse method and if onResponse doesn't work,setadapter to recyclerview doesn't work to.And 
VideoApi class:

```
public interface VideoApi {

    @GET("/videos/featured")
    Call<List<Video>>getFeaturedVideo();
}
```

Video class:

```
public class Video {

    @SerializedName("url")
    @Expose
    private String url;
    @SerializedName("title")
    @Expose
    private String title;
    @SerializedName("description")
    @Expose
    private String description;
    @SerializedName("score")
    @Expose
    private Integer score;

    /**
     *
     * @return
     * The url
     */
    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param url
     * The url
     */
    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     * The title
     */
    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param title
     * The title
     */
    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     * The description
     */
    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param description
     * The description
     */
    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     * The score
     */
    public Integer getScore() {
        return score;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param score
     * The score
     */
    public void setScore(Integer score) {
        this.score = score;
    }

}
```

FeaturedFragment:

```
public class FeaturedFragment extends Fragment {
    RecyclerViewAdapter recyclerViewAdapter;
    public static final String ROOT_URL = "https://api.vid.me/";
    public List <Video> videos;
    RecyclerView recList;

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_featured, container, false);
        recList = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.cardList);
        recList.setHasFixedSize(true);
        LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        llm.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        recList.setLayoutManager(llm);
        try {
            getVideos();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return rootView;
    }

    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    }

    private void getVideos() throws IOException {
        Retrofit retrofitAdapter = new Retrofit.Builder()
.addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .baseUrl(ROOT_URL)
                .build();
        final VideoApi videoApi = retrofitAdapter.create(VideoApi.class);
Call<List<Video>> call = videoApi.getFeaturedVideo();
        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Video>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<Video>> call, Response<List<Video>> response) {
                Log.d("MainActivity", "Status Code = " + response.code());
                videos.addAll(response.body());
                recyclerViewAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(videos);
                String result = response.body().get(0).getTitle();
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), result, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                recList.setAdapter(recyclerViewAdapter);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<Video>> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: Did you declared INTERNET permission in your Manifest file ?

Comment: of course I did it.Puted <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/> in manifest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your json response returns array of `Video` objects.
Change `List<Video>` everywhere in your `Call` object to `Videos`
where `Videos`class is be defined as -

```
public class Videos {
    List<Video> videos;
}
```

Change like this -

```
Call<Videos> call = videoApi.getFeaturedVideo();
        call.enqueue(new Callback<Videos>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Videos> call, Response<Videos> response) {
                Log.d("MainActivity", "Status Code = " + response.code());
                videos = response.body().videos;
                recyclerViewAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(videos);                   
                recList.setAdapter(recyclerViewAdapter);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Videos> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });

    }
```

Also, change -

```
@GET("/videos/featured")
Call<Videos>getFeaturedVideo();
```

Comment: I dont understant what you mean,sorry

Comment: why is this like this? Actually the other declaration should also work right?